# RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter of Langchain doesn't exist

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, text-chunking

I am trying to do a text chunking by LangChain's RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter model. I have install langchain(pip install langchain[all]), but the program still report there is no RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter package. I use from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter I tried to find something on the python file of langchain and get nothing helpful. Anyone meet the same problem? Thank you for your time!

If anyone knows how to solve it, that will be great.

Comment: langchain is not good: https://youtu.be/ygehmBjwtiw

Comment: There have been a lot of questions recently around langchain (just search stackoverflow). It may not be as robust as it could be

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try below steps.

Create a virtual environment using the command

```
    python -m venv my_venv_name
```

Activate the virtual environment by executing source

```
    my_venv_name/bin/activate
```

PIP install libraries

```
   pip install langchain==0.0.208 
   pip install """Other required libraries like OpenAI etc..
```

You should now successfully able to import

```
    from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
```

Also, you can check

your langchain environment path, something as /langchain_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/text_splitter.py, here you you should see the definition of RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

Comment: I installed langchain 0.0.39 and it doesnt work. Then I followed your directions to install 0.0.208 and it work. Do you know the reason why 0.0.39 doesnt work?

Comment: 0.0.39 seems to be very old version, not able to find on github as well. I see oldest version 0.0.64 https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/releases?page=22 , which is also having RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter. So you can use any version based on your requirement between 0.0.64 to current latest version 0.0.268. Latest stable version is always recommended.

Comment: Got it. I thought 0.0.39 is newer than 0.0.208 cause it starts from '3' newer than '2' lol. Ok I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In my env, I have

```bash
pip list | grep langchain
langchain                    0.0.262
```

then the following should work

```py
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
```

Comment: That should work too. It is just the version reason. I used a too old version to import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter